# Last computer account password change via Powershell

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

Does anybody know how to get last computer account password change for all servers in a domain via powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.rlmueller.net/PwdLastChanged.htm

http://blogs.metcorpconsulting.com/tech/?p=1369
From the above link :

```
Import-Module activedirectory
[int]$ComputerPasswordAgeDays = 90
IF ((test-path "c:\temp") -eq $False) { md "c:\temp" }
$ExportFile = "c:\temp\InactiveWorkstations.csv"
$ComputerStaleDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$ComputerPasswordAgeDays)
$InactiveWorkstations = Get-ADComputer -filter { (passwordLastSet -le $ComputerStaleDate) -and (OperatingSystem -notlike "*Server*") -and (OperatingSystem -like "*Windows*") } -properties Name, DistinguishedName, OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack, passwordLastSet,LastLogonDate,Description
$InactiveWorkstations | export-csv $ExportFile
```

Comment: Pretty good!

Used the attribute name from the first article in conjunction with dsquery tool to get info about all servers in a domain:

dsquery * -scope subtree -attr "cn" "operatingSystem" "operatingSystemServicePack" "pwdLastSet" -filter "(&(objectclass=computer)(objectcategory=computer)(operatingSystem=Windows Server*))" -limit 10000 -uco >C:\output.txt

Comment: Perhaps, it is worth mentioning what values returned by pwdLastSet attribute are not human readable at all.
Here is an article on how to convert these values into human readable [Converting LDAP dates](http://maxvit.net/convert_ldap_dates)